# ajax on parked domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, dns

I'm currently writing this jquery and for some reason (I don't know why) it works on the normal domain, but on the parked domain it doesn't.

Normal domain - http://www.thefinishedbox.com
Parked domain - http://www.tfbox.com

If you scroll down to the colony news and hit the click me link you'll see it will retrieve data via jquery ajax on the Normal domain, but on the parked domain it wont.

Here is the jQuery code I have so far (its pretty standard):

```
$(function() {

$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "Load me plz";

//    load() functions
var loadUrl = "http://thefinishedbox.com/wp-content/themes/tfbox-beta/test.php";

$('.overlay').css({
    opacity: '0'
});
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').css({
        display: 'block'
    }).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 300);

    $(".overlay .content").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);

    return false;
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, 300);
    $('.overlay').queue(function() {
        $(this).css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
    return false;
});
```

I'm a complete noob when it comes to ajax so any help would be massivly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't do Ajax requests on another domain, unless you have set permissions accordingly. It's called "Cross-Domain Ajax".

If you absolutly need to make it work, you can modify your code a bit:

```
var loadUrl = "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/wp-content/themes/tfbox-beta/test.php";
```

Or use a workaround (not recommended) : http://www.usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: Yea i just read up on it, surely I should have done that prior to posting this question, by the way, do you know anything about setting permissions?

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but just fyi, it should be "...domain, unless you have set permissions accordingly."

Comment: That's not correct, it operates on hostname+port not domain.  Also, as he is talking about a "parked domain", I'd guess that the content isn't available on the site he's running the script on, so window.location.hostname won't work - and is unnecessary anyway, as you can just use a relative URL.

Comment: @Jim @Eric Gagnon @JMC Creative window.location.hostname did work, but If you feel thats the wrong direction to with, if there's a better, more solid approach to doing this please let me know and i'll go about learning it.

Comment: If it works, then that's fine, go with it.  I misunderstood what you meant by "parked domain".  Usually it implies there's no content on the site yet.

Comment: @Jim Ok i'll stick to it for now, but I will definiatly read more into this in a month or so. Thanks for your time

Comment: Maybe your parked domain could redirect traffic to your main domain. That's what I do most of the time. If you don't have a good reason to have two domains, maybe you should do that! Nice website btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests are normally prohibited from loading things from other hostnames for security reasons.  If you could simply load things from other sites, you could load people's bank details, etc.

A common way of working around this restriction is to use JSON-P, but that requires support from the other website.

Comment: Any tips on how I would go about this? A page about it? Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: There's tonnes of JSON-P tutorials around.  Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this on your php page to store the domainname in a js variable. That way you can use the same code on either domain.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var domain = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourJavascriptFile.js"></script>
```

then use that variable in your js file, like so:

```
//    load() functions
var loadUrl = domain + "/wp-content/themes/tfbox-beta/test.php";
```

Comment: I quite like this approach, it does seem a little more logical, though I'm not sure if i'll use it this time, I may use it later on though. Thanks!